# Setting datatable options in R Shiny

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

I have a datatable in Shiny, and I am trying to make the last column unclickable (because the column contains buttons of its own). I have found datatable documentation (https://datatables.net/reference/option/select.selector) that says the javascript to do that is:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
select: {
    style:    'os',
    selector: 'td:not(:last-child)'
}
} );
```

However I cannot get these options passed to the Shiny datatable correctly. This is what I am trying:

```
library(shiny)
require(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
   DTOutput("table")
)
server <- function(input, output) {

output$table<-renderDT({
  datatable(iris, options = list(select.selector=list(style="os", selector='td:not(:last-child)')))
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As far as I can tell, Shiny completely ignores the option when I run it.

Comment: My only guess is that the shiny function overwrites the arguments I'm trying to pass using select.selector. I've done more research on getting row selection to play nice with buttons and have the problem referenced in the Github issues without any working solutions: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/178

Comment: I would try `datatable(iris, extensions="Select", options = list(select=list(style="os", selector='td:not(:last-child)')))`.